# How to get a Dynamic Video URL

Tags: php, dynamic, dynamic-data

im looking for a Solution, to get a Video URL from a VideoWebsite.

Here is a sample video: XXXX

And here is the dynamic link to the video: XXX

Cause its dynamic i cant find the url, or have no clue how the urls get generated in php. I searched for php functions, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to parse (and probably run) the actual SWF file that gets embedded and is responsible for playing the video, and see what requests it makes to get that actual content URL.

Doing this in pure PHP is a highly complex enterprise (if possible at all) and not for the faint of heart. I'm not aware of a ready-made solution that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't answer the technical side of your question, if you're parsing videos from someone else's website, you might be best off contacting the site/content owners and asking how you can properly link to their content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this link to get the plain player SWF:

```
http://www.collegehumor.com/moogaloop/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1946215&autostart=true
```

where clip_id holds the same id as seen in the url. I guess this is the best compromise as I doubt CollegeHumour wants you to get the plain movie, which also may lead to copyright issues.